# Enable Google My Business API. Api calls failed

Tags: google-api, google-api-client, google-apis-explorer, google-my-business-api

I tried to access GMB account list api with an access token having scope
`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/business.manage`

```
{
"error": {
"code": 403,
"message": "Google My Business API has not been used in project xxxxxx before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/mybusiness.googleapis.com/overview?project=xxxxxx then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.",
"status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
"details": [
  {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.Help",
    "links": [
      {
        "description": "Google developers console API activation",
        "url": "https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/mybusiness.googleapis.com/overview?project=xxxxx"
      }
    ]
  }
]
}
}
```

Whenever I tried to submit request from I got an email from GMB that
`Your company already has a whitelisted project to access the Google My Business API. At this time, we are only whitelisting one project per business.`.

I checked, but there is no library with name Google My Business.

Current enabled Libraries are

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you submitted the form to get access to the GMB API?
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfC_FKSWzbSae_5rOpgwFeIUzXUF1JCQnlsZM_gC1I2UHjA3w/viewform

When you fill it, you have to precise the email addresses that Google will grant access to. Maybe someone else filled in for your company but didn't mention your email address.

In my case, when I received a confirmation email from the GMB team, I was able to see the GMB API when I searched for it in the console (see screenshot)

[image]

Then, all I had to do was to click to enable it.

Comment: Already submitted. 
There some issue with some other project, We had sent email to them and they removed the old project.